# List::contains with comparator

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there any way (method, lambda, or elegant construct) to find an element in a list based on a given comparator?

I wrote a method like this:

```
private static <T> boolean contains(List<T> list, T item, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    return list.stream()
            .anyMatch(listItem -> comparator.compare(listItem, item) == 0
            );
}
```

But I'm looking to replace it with something that would be more elegant.

I don't want to add any dependency, so no Guava, "commons", etc. I'm really looking for a pretty way to do this in Java 8.

EDIT: Some example of what I'd consider more elegant (here is the using code):

```
// sadly, this method doesn't exist
// nor is there a static one in Collections
// but maybe you can think of another way?
if (list.containsSame(item, comparator)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Well, how doesn't the code you write satisfy you? It looks just fine (although in the signature I'd have supplied a `Comparator<? super T>` instead)

Comment: I'm feeling it could be improved by smart usage of the platform or language.

Comment: using streams with your own comparators is pretty much what most people would call "smart usage of the framework". Thats also the most "pretty" way because of lambda. What more could you want?

Comment: @specializt That's the question. Out of experience, I think it can be improved further. I'll edit with an example of (non-existing) method that I'd consider better/simpler.

Comment: @fge edited my question with your signature. We can improve List<T>, but I'll stop here as the aim of this question is to remove this method altogether and replace it with something simpler.

Comment: Well, you can always extend `Stream` and supply a new method with a `default` implementation

Comment: you can create a new class which implements `Collection` or `List` and modify that to your needs.

Comment: @specializt that would require to use my own implementation of List everywhere, just because some methods need to find something in the list.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what you were asking about. Either use your own collections or use functions like all of the ones posted in this question, there is no other possibility because everything else doesnt make sense - you COULD add methods to classes like ArrayList via bytecode manipulation frameworks but thats likely to be erroneus and absolute overkill. You want something which is nigh-impossible.

Comment: @specializt I want an existing method or a trivial lambda. I don't want any bytecode magic. Just because you or me didn't yet find anything that would fulfill this goal, doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Holger's answer seems interesting, I need to think about it.

Comment: All of the posted snippets are basically modified or extended versions of your own.

Comment: Convince Oracle to add `containsSame` in Java 9, or switch to a language with extension methods.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, there is no built-in functionality directly addressing this task. So since you can’t avoid creating utility methods (if you want reduce code duplication), it’s worth thinking about which kind of utility method could be useful in other scenarios as well.

E.g. if it was my project I knew there are almost always methods for partial function application flying around, like:

```
public static <T,U,R> Function<U,R> bind(BiFunction<T,U,R> f, T t) {
    return u -> f.apply(t, u);
}
```

Utilizing this existing method, a solution could look like:

```
static <T> boolean contains(List<T> list, T item, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
  return list.stream().map(bind(comparator::compare, item))
                      .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(0));
}
```

But this is not necessarily the best solution.

Another approach could be to have a method for converting a `Comparator` into an equality `BiPredicate` and a utility method for partial application of a `BiPredicate`:

```
public static <T> BiPredicate<T,T> match(Comparator<T> f) {
    return (a,b)->f.compare(a, b)==0;
}
public static <T,U> Predicate<U> bind(BiPredicate<T,U> f, T t) {
    return u -> f.test(t, u);
}
```

Then the `contains` method becomes as simple as

```
static <T> boolean contains(List<T> list, T item, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
  return list.stream().anyMatch(bind(match(comparator), item));
}
```

But this is only a simplification if the utility methods can be used at other places of your project as well. On the other hand, they are of such a general nature that similar methods might be added as `default` methods to the function interfaces in a subsequent Java release. In this case your code using such utility methods is prepared for migration to that newer version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the next methods [from the `commons-collections` version 4+](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html):

- `IterableUtils.contains(Iterable<? extends E> iterable, E object, Equator<? super E> equator)` - Checks if the object is contained in the given iterable.
- `IterableUtils.matchesAny(Iterable<E> iterable, Predicate<? super E> predicate)` - Answers true if a predicate is true for any element of the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is what you want, but one possibility is to create your own interface extending `Stream` and provide the method you want (NOTE: UNTESTED):

```
public interface MyStream<R>
    extends Stream<R>
{
    // Yay! Static methods in interfaces!
    public static <E> MyStream<E> of(final Collection<E> collection)
    {
        return new MyStreamImpl<E>(collection);
    }

    // Yay! Default methods in interfaces!
    default boolean containsAny(R item, Comparator<? super R> comparator)
    {
        return anyMatch(e -> comparator.compare(item, e) == 0);
    }
}

public class MyStreamImpl<R>
    implements MyStream<R>
{
    private final Stream<R> stream;

    public MyStreamImpl(final Collection<R> collection)
    {
        this.stream = Objects.requireNonNull(collection.stream());
    }

    // delegate all other operations to stream
}
```

Then you could use:

```
MyStream.of(someList).containsAny(item, comparator);
```

(but that's a lot of code for not much, really)

Comment: This means wrapping the stream in this instead of just calling the method. I want to get rid of my extra code, which I'd like to replace with something easier.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to create an extra function in first place? Just call each time the stream functions.

If you insist, instead of a `Comparator` you can use a `BiPredicate`.

For example.

```
BiPredicate<Integer,Integer> greaterThan = (i,s) -> i > s;
```

And change your contain function to something like

```
private static <T> boolean containsp(List<T> list, T item, BiPredicate<? super T,? super T> biPredicate)     {
    return list.stream().filter(l-> biPredicate.test(l,item) ).findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

I don't know if it's more elegant but it seems to work.

Comment: I don't want to create an extra function. I'd rather get rid of it.

Comment: The just use `list.stream().anyMatch(listItem -> *and place here your expression* );`. Where does the answers not meet your needs.

Comment: This expression is repeated in 5 different places in my code. I want something reusable, that's why I have this method. I don't actually insist on this method, I guess there will be a simpler way with standard Java APIs.