# Java 8 streams: getting lists of objects by property inside of an object in the object

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to do the following:

- I have 3 objects `User`, `Basket` and `Appliance`
- `User` contains `Basket`, `Basket` contains a `List` of `Appliance` and `Appliance` contains a `String applianceName`.

I have a list of users and I want to get the user that has a certain appliance in one Java 8 Stream.

Code:

```
Appliance appliance1 = new Appliance();
    appliance1.setApplianceName("something1");
    Appliance appliance2 = new Appliance();
    appliance2.setApplianceName("something2");
    Appliance appliance3 = new Appliance();
    appliance3.setApplianceName("something3");
    Appliance appliance4 = new Appliance();
    appliance4.setApplianceName("something4");

    List<Appliance> applianceList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    applianceList1.add(appliance1);
    applianceList1.add(appliance2);
    applianceList1.add(appliance3);
    applianceList1.add(appliance4);
    List<Appliance> applianceList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    applianceList2.add(appliance1);
    applianceList2.add(appliance3);

    Basket basket1 = new Basket();
    basket1.setApple(1);
    basket1.setApplianceList(applianceList1);
    Basket basket2 = new Basket();
    basket2.setApple(5);
    basket2.setApplianceList(applianceList2);

    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setFirstmName("Jane");
    user1.setLastName("Doe");
    user1.setBasket(basket1);

    User user2 = new User();
    user2.setFirstmName("John");
    user2.setLastName("Doe");
    user2.setBasket(basket2);

    List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    usersList.add(user1);
    usersList.add(user2);
```

I tried:

```
usersList.stream()
            .map(User::getBasket)
            .map(Basket::getApplianceList)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(Appliance::getApplianceName)
            .filter(applianceName -> applianceName.equals("something1"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the above code return the appliance name and I want the `User` that has a `Basket` that has the `Appliance` in the `List`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List::contains with comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269675/listcontains-with-comparator)

Comment: No, I don't need a comparator, I want to get to the `applianceList` of the users in the `usersList` and take that `User` object if it contains a given appliance.

Comment: With a comparator you could just stream the users and see if the appliance list contains "something1".

Comment: I know that, but I want to do it specifically with java 8 streams, because I came upon an example I can't solve with java streams. Also, it is not simple comparison, I need the `Users` from the `usersList` that have a given `Appliance`

Comment: Streaming is Java 8. Stream the users and filter on applianceList contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want something like this:

```
List<User> result =  usersList.stream()
            .filter(user -> user.getBasket().getApplianceList().stream()
                 .anyMatch(appliance -> 
                          appliance.getApplianceName().equals("something1")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```